# Hive Variables in Hue

Tags: datetime, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hue

While trying to declare a variable ,then run a query using that variable in Hive on Hue (web client) .It is not working.

```
set MAX_DATE='2017-05-22 07:35:25';

select * from tablea where datetime = ${hivevar:Max_Date} limit 1
```

Following error message is seen:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:83
>   cannot recognize input near '$' '{' 'hivevar' in expression
>   specification

Comment: Web-client has menu `Enable Parameterization` and `settings` for adding key-value

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
set MAX_DATE='2017-05-22 07:35:25';

select * from tablea where datetime = '${hivevar:MAX_DATE}' limit 1;
```